# Filter RecyclerView results using SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I'm working to filter the results of `RecyclerView`. Here is the main layout xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable name="viewmodel" type="TestViewModel"/>
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_accounts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:queryHint="@string/text_hint_filter_accounts"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_account_picker_title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_account_picker_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/list_accounts"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_accounts"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The adapter class implements `Filterable`, here is the code snippet for `getFilter()`

```
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object: Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            constraint?.let {
                val constraintString = constraint.toString()
                searchList = if(constraintString.isEmpty()) accounts
                 else {
                    val filteredList = arrayListOf<AccountDataEntity>()
                    for(account in accounts) {
                        if(account.Name!!.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) filteredList.add(account)
                    }
                    searchList = filteredList
                    searchList
                }
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = searchList
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            searchList = results?.values as List<AccountDataEntity>
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

How do you bind search query text changes to trigger filter function on the adapter?

I tried the following on the SearchView on xml

```
app:onQueryTextChange="@{() -> viewmodel.onQueryChange(searchAccounts.getText().toString())}"
```

But, the build failed with the following error

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:onQueryTextChange' with parameter type lambda on
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.

Has anyone know how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel add

```
@BindingAdapter("queryTextListener")
public static void setOnQueryTextListener(val searchView: SearchView,val listener:SearchView.OnQueryTextListener) {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener)
}
```

Also modify XML like,

```
app:queryTextListener="@{vm.onQueryTextListener}"
```